# How to replace text with Image / Table in OpenXML (C# .Net core 3.1)

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am just using OpenXML for manipulating docx document. I have templates that has notation like
{{userFirstName}}
{{tableOfUsers}}
{{signatureImage}} etc

I need to replace those text with table, image etc. How to do that in Openxml ?
I'm using C# .Net core 3.1 with OpenXML 2.5

My code was like this, but the table still not inserted into the right place:

```
    var fileName = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "test/test.docx");
    var fileNameResult = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "test/result.docx");

    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
        using (WordprocessingDocument wd = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
        {
            Table table = new Table();

            // Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
            TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
                new TableBorders(
                    new TopBorder()
                    {
                        Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                        Size = 24
                    },
                    new BottomBorder()
                    {
                        Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                        Size = 24
                    },
                    new LeftBorder()
                    {
                        Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                        Size = 24
                    },
                    new RightBorder()
                    {
                        Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                        Size = 24
                    },
                    new InsideHorizontalBorder()
                    {
                        Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                        Size = 24
                    },
                    new InsideVerticalBorder()
                    {
                        Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                        Size = 24
                    }
                )
            );

            // Append the TableProperties object to the empty table.
            table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tblProp);

            // Create a row.
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            // Create a cell.
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();

            // Specify the width property of the table cell.
            tc1.Append(new TableCellProperties(
                new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "2400" }));

            // Specify the table cell content.
            tc1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("some text"))));

            // Append the table cell to the table row.
            tr.Append(tc1);

            // Create a second table cell by copying the OuterXml value of the first table cell.
            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(tc1.OuterXml);

            // Append the table cell to the table row.
            tr.Append(tc2);

            // Append the table row to the table.
            table.Append(tr);  
            var tblStr = table.ToString();

            //wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);
            Text tablePl = wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>().Where(x => x.Text == "{{tableOfUsers}}").First();
            if(tablePl != null)
            {
                var parent = tablePl.Parent;
                tablePl.Parent.InsertAfter<Table>(table, tablePl);
                tablePl.Remove();
            }

            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wd.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Regex regexText = new Regex("{{name}}");
            docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Claire " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            // Regex regextable = new Regex("{{tableOfUsers}}");
            // docText = regextable.Replace(docText, tblStr);


            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wd.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }
        }
        await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(fileNameResult, stream.ToArray());
    }

    _fileRepo.SetPath("test");
    string fileName2 = "result.docx";
    var data = await _fileRepo.DownloadFile(fileName2);
    return File(data, "application/octet-stram", "filename.docx");
}
```

My docx file looks like

> Hello {{name}}
>
> Here is the list of users : {{tableOfUsers}}
>
> Sincerely,
>
> {{signatureImage}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below to insert a table:

```
............
string tablePlaceholder = "{{tableOfUsers}}";
Text tablePl = wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
    .Descendants<Text>()
    .Where(x => x.Text.Contains(tablePlaceholder))
    .First();
if (tablePl != null)
{
    //Insert the table after the paragraph.
    var parent = tablePl.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    parent.InsertAfter(table, tablePl.Parent.Parent);
    tablePl.Text = tablePl.Text.Replace(tablePlaceholder, "");
    wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}

string docText = wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OuterXml;
Regex regexText = new Regex("{{name}}");
docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Claire " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body(docText);
wd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
.............
```

<s>You are looking for `{{table}}` in your code, but the notation in your template is `{{tableOfUsers}}`.</s>

Comment: sorry, it was code from my experiment page, i have edited so it will suit with the current template

Comment: @nightingale2k1 I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: var parent = tablePl.Parent.Parent.Parent; 

why you go to Parent.Parent.Parent ?

Comment: @nightingale2k1 It just makes the result looks good, you should use a correct parent to insert the table. In this example, the table is needed to insert after the paragraph not the text. You can check out the XML structure of the document.

Comment: thank you for you help. it work. I just confuse about the structure. :)

Comment: @nightingale2k1 It depends on the actual document, so make sure your code fit to it. You can check the output of the variable `docText `.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DocxTemplater for Net](https://github.com/Amberg/DocxTemplater). It is a library that does exactly what you are trying to do.

Create a template document with template syntax

```
This Text: {{ds.Title}} - will be replaced
```

Open the template, add a model and store the result to a file

```cs
   var template = DocxTemplate.Open("template.docx");
   template.BindModel("ds", new { Title = "Some Text"});
   template.Save("generated.docx");
```

It can handle Tables, Images, Html and much more

Full Disclosure: I am the author of this library.